# Matplotlib: combine legend with same color and name

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I repeat the plot with same color and label name, the label would appear multiple times:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x_labels = [10,20,30]
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,1,5,1]

for label in x_labels:
    x_3d = label*np.ones_like(x)
    ax.plot(x_3d, x, y, color='black', label='GMM')

ax.legend()
```

[image]

Is it possible to make them into one, combing the same lables legends into one? Something like

[image]

I can produce the above pic by

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x_labels = [10,20,30]
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,1,5,1]
legend = False

for label in x_labels:
    x_3d = label*np.ones_like(x)
    ax.plot(x_3d, x, y, color='black', label='GMM')
    if legend == False:
        ax.legend()
        legend = True
```

But this feels very ugly, is there any good sotion? Or do I simply make the plot in a wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only show the label for one of the three sets of data. The can be done by adding an if/else statement in the `label = ...` in `ax.plot()`. Below is an example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x_labels = [10,20,30]
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,1,5,1]

for label in x_labels:
    x_3d = label*np.ones_like(x)
    ax.plot(x_3d, x, y, color='black', label='GMM' if label == x_labels[0] else '') 
    # above only shows the label for the first plot

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

This gives the following graph:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you have different colors then you could use the following to show the legend only once for each color:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x_labels = [10,20,30,40,50]
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,1,5,1]

colors = ['black','red','black','orange','orange']
labels = ['GMM','Other 1','GMM','Other 2','Other 2']
some_list= []

for i in range(len(x_labels)):
    x_3d = x_labels[i]*np.ones_like(x)
    ax.plot(x_3d, x, y, color=colors[i], label=labels[i] if colors[i] not in some_list else '')

    if colors.count(colors[i])>1:
        some_list.append(colors[i])

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

This gives the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works. But it would be good if we can combine legend with same name and same color.

Comment: @DavidG I guess he maybe wants such a function for Legend object / or an argument for the `legend()` function which can automatically merge legends with the same name and color, just like: `legend.merge_the_same()` or `ax.legend(merge_same=True)`